# How to adapt WSGI application by uri query params in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, wsgi, werkzeug

I'm working on using Tornado 4 with werkzeug debug tool together, but the output of werkzeug traceback requires css and js file in the uri `localhost/?__debug__=True...`.

I need to adapt requests with `?__debug__=True` to werkzeug debug app, but don't know how to deal with it.

The Tornado 3 version is here: https://gist.github.com/kxxoling/00f5bb306b5a3398fa0d . But not working on Tornado 4 because of API changes.

Answer (score 0):

`tornado.web.Application` does not support routing based on a query parameter.

It looks like what you need is an implementation of [`HTTPServerConnectionDelegate`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerConnectionDelegate), which delegates to either an `Application` or `WSGIContainer` depending on the requested URI. This is the replacement for the `__call__` interface used in the linked gist.